# BottomSheet - Incorrect Design Behavior

Tags: android, xamarin

I have been trying to set the `Bottomsheet` the way Google is using in their apps such as GOOGLE NEWS etc,

> This is how Google's `Bottomsheet` looks like the following

[image]

> Where my `Bottomsheet` looks like the following

[image]

Stright away you will notice two things,

1. **There are no rounded corners**
2. **The navigation at the bottom is not blended**

My code for `bottomsheet` is the following (i removed the controls for simplicity purposes)

**MyBottomSheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">           
              <!--controls here-->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I am calling it in my code as follows

```
View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyBottomSheet, null);
Dialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
dialog.SetContentView(view);
```

How can I get Rounded corners and make sure the bottom navigation does not go transparent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the Google's modal BottomSheet design, implement it the following way.  Start by creating a shape drawable which will be used as background for the bottom sheet:

**bg_bottomsheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/bottom_sheet_corner_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/bottom_sheet_corner_radius" />
    <padding android:top="@dimen/bottom_sheet_top_padding" />
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
```

Now create a custom style for the BottomSheet widget.

**style-v21.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog" />

</resources>
```

Now, extend the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and set the new theme on it. That's it!

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply, I tried different things in your reply but I have been completely lost, so Basically, the first thing I did was to implement simply the Rounded corners and I failed. also, what do you mean by EXTEND the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Comment: Apologies, I missed your previous comment regarding your doubt. Glad it worked!

Comment: No problem :) thanks for your help, it looks beautiful now just like Google ..  cheers

Answer (score 5):

Now, I use this

```xml
    <!-- Stuff to make the bottom sheet with round top borders -->
    <style name="BottomSheetShapeAppearance" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetModal" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/BottomSheetShapeAppearance</item>
        <item name="behavior_peekHeight">140dp</item>
        <item name="behavior_fitToContents">true</item>
        <item name="behavior_halfExpandedRatio">0.5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BaseBottomSheetMenu" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetModal</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetMenuTheme" parent="@style/BaseBottomSheetMenu" />
```

You can change general theme support in `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog`extend by
`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog` for Dark Mode

In create BotoomSheet load specific theme

```kotlin
    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetMenuTheme
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use below code

```
View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyBottomSheet, null);
Dialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
dialog.SetContentView(view);
((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) view.getParent())
                .getLayoutParams();
((View) view.getParent()).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```